# What options are there to render Javascript "document.write" code serverside with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, server-side, server-side-rendering

The vendor that we are using for a piece of software has an API that returns raw javascript. The intention is to have a script tag with the API as the source. Our smaller pages have 70+ client-side requests to populate the page with all the required data. The response looks something like this:

```
document.write("\u003cdiv class=\"cal home_events\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cdate blue\"\u003e\u003cp class=\"date\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23719&information_id=38921&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003e8/28\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cinfo home_event_decs\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23719&information_id=38921&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003eGetting Started with Next Generation Classrooms - Incubator Classroom\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cal home_events\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cdate blue\"\u003e\u003cp class=\"date\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23756&information_id=39010&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003e8/28\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cinfo home_event_decs\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23756&information_id=39010&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003eGmail and Calendar Tips and Tricks\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cal home_events\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cdate blue\"\u003e\u003cp class=\"date\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23752&information_id=38995&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003e8/28\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cinfo home_event_decs\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23752&information_id=38995&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003eCreating Accessible and Fillable Electronic Forms\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cal home_events\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cdate blue\"\u003e\u003cp class=\"date\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23720&information_id=38923&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003e8/28\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cinfo home_event_decs\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23720&information_id=38923&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003eGetting Started with Next Generation Classrooms - General\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cal home_events\"\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cdate blue\"\u003e\u003cp class=\"date\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23881&information_id=39283&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003e8/28\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv class=\"cinfo home_event_decs\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"http://events.sjsu.edu/EventList.aspx?view=EventDetails&eventidn=23881&information_id=39283&type=&syndicate=syndicate\" target=\"blank\" \u003eComedySportz Improv Show\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e");
```

As you can see, a DOM structure is being built and printed to the page where it's called. What I would like to do is render the response serverside for a smoother user experience. We're running PHP on our backend. I'm not sure if V8js is a solution - I can't find any examples where a `document.write` is used or V8js being used outside the context of React.

Comment: replace `document.write` with `echo`?

Answer (score 0):

If by this you mean you want to build the js code backend (it'll still load front end though as html pages do with js)

PHP uses echo

so:

```
echo "whatever you want to output";
```

or

```
$output = "<script>$(document.ready(function(){
alert('hi');
});</script>"

echo $output;
```